Is AtomicIntegers thread safe and the output of the code is nondeterministic or deterministic?
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class Counter implements Runnable {
    private static AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(3);

    public void run() {
        System.out.print(i.getAndDecrement());
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Counter());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Counter());
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Counter());
        Thread[] threads = {t1, t2, t3};
        for(Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}

I ran this code many times and I always get 321 as the answer but I am not sure this code can get any other output.

i isn't the only contended resource here. What about System.out?

When I run the code multiple times, I get various outputs.  312, 213, 321 ...

in this example, AtomicInteger only guarantees that you will get the numbers 1, 2, and 3 each only once; but it does not control the sequence in which the numbers will be printed (for example, the threads can be interrupted exactly after calling getAndDecrement() but before print() is called) -- an example without AtomicInteger, i.e. using a pure int, would be able to produce an output like 332 or 323


Is AtomicIntegers thread safe.

Yes.  In your example, getAndDecrement is guaranteed to subtract 1 from the AtomicInteger, and return the pre-decremented value.

and the output of the code is nondeterministic or deterministic?

For me it is nondeterministic.  I get a variety of orders of 1, 2 & 3 when I run your example on my machine.
There are at least two places where there is non-determinism in your example:

The threads may be initially scheduled to run in different orders.  That means that order in which the three threads call getAndDecrement may differ.

The code is also implicitly synchronizing in the output stack.  The order in which threads acquire a contended lock is non-deterministic.


(Note that while there is nondeterminism in 1, it is not the cause of the nondeterministic output.  That is caused by 2.)

System.out not chronological
When calling System.out.println across threads, the output does not necessarily appear on the console in chronological order.  I have seen the order mixed up many times.
Always include a timestamp with your System.out calls when using multiple threads. I suggest Instant.now(). And study those timestamps when you care about the sequence order.
Alternatively, rather than use System.out, deposit your messages into a thread-safe collection. Or use a proper logging tool.
AtomicInteger
Regarding your use of AtomicInteger:

Read correct Answer by Stephen C.
You correctly instantiate the AtomicInteger object before any possible usage. That’s good.
I would generally make any Atomic… variable final to avoid inadvertently reassigning a different instance.
Your use of static with i seems awkward to me. Having three instances of Counter that interact to affect one another seems counter-intuitive, misleading, and confusing to me. I would instead use something like a Singleton, or would share the same instance of Counter across threads. Perhaps my concern is more style than substance, and reasonable people might disagree — but I don’t think so.

ExecutorService
In modern Java we rarely address the Thread class directly.
Instead, learn about the Executors framework added to Java 5. Write your task as a separate class (or lambda) that implements Runnable/Callable. Submit instance(s) of your task class/lambda to an instance of ExecutorService produced by the Executors utility class.

Unfortunately, almost all of the techniques that one can use to observe the order of events in a multi-threaded application will potentially change the order or record the order inaccurately.  For example, a thread-safe collection will can a synchronizing effect, sampling the clock has undefined properties, logging tools can synchronize, etc.  It is a really difficult problem.

The output of System.out is ordered (as in, the output actually written first into the buffer of System.out, will be first on the console), but access to this buffer uses synchronized, so under contention (which is likely to happen here), it means that it is not deterministic in which order the threads are actually writing to the buffer of the PrintStream (System.out).
